# PHP: Sort JSON data by keys

Tags: php, json, sorting

I want to sort a single line of JSON data by the keys alphabetically using PHP. So in the end:

```
{"one":"morning","two":"afternoon","three":"evening","four":"night"}
```

becomes:

```
{"four":"night","one":"morning","three":"evening","two":"afternoon"}
```

I've tried using `ksort` to no avail:

```
$icons = json_decode(file_get_contents("icons.json"));
ksort($icons);
foreach($icons as $icon => $code){...}
```

Comment: Can you post the PHP code you used?

Comment: Did you call `json_decode()` first?

Comment: `$arr = json_decode($yourJSONString); ksort($arr);`

Comment: did you var_dump the array to see if it has been correctly read?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ksort works with arrays, not with strings:

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
ksort($array);
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: Perfect; needed to add the "true"! Cheers guys!

Comment: If that solved your problem you can accept the answer. @deceze, these points should go to you :-)

Comment: Can this method be used for nested data?  That is, sort each level of nesting by its keys?

Answer (score 2):

In order to use `ksort`, you first have to convert the json to PHP array by using:

```
// the true argument specifies that it needs to be converted into a PHP array
$array = json_encode($your_json, true);
```

Then apply [ksort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) on that array.

And finally `json_encode` it again to get the result back in json.

Answer (score 0):

**this way here:**

```
var dataArr = [];
for (value in oldData) {
    var tmp = oldData[key];
    dataArr.push(parseInt(key)tmp});
}

dataArr.sort(function(a, b){
    if (a.word < b.word) return -1;
    if (b.word < a.word) return 1;
    return 0;
});
```

**now in dataArr you have your sorted data**